# Building and running FsCheck.Xunit tests in an F# ionide project

Tags: f#, f#-fake, ionide

I created a standalone `console` application using the `yo fsharp` generator. The github repo concerning this particular question is here: https://github.com/KurtRMueller/PascalsTriangleKata.

I'd like to build and run some basic `FsCheck.Xunit` tests. I'm aware that I need to add some targets to `FAKE`'s `build.fsx`, but as I'm quite new to .net and the `C#`/`F#` ecosystem, I don't know how to do that.

The example from the `FAKE` example page is as follows:

```
// define test dlls
let testDlls = !! (testDir + "/Test.*.dll")

Target "xUnitTest" (fun _ ->
    testDlls
        |> xUnit (fun p ->
             {p with
                ShadowCopy = false;
                HtmlOutput = true;
                XmlOutput = true;
                OutputDir = testDir })
)
```

I'm not quite sure how to build the these `Test` dlls.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to write the tests in some language (F# ?) and then build them into a DLL the same way you build your regular (non-test) code. Is there something specific you're having trouble with?

Comment: I have a basic test: https://github.com/KurtRMueller/PascalsTriangleKata/blob/master/TriangleProperties.fs

How do I build that file into a dll?

Comment: Same way you build your non-test code?

Comment: When I run the build command using Ionide's `FAKE` config, it doesn't build dll files from my test files.

Comment: I don't quite get what you're asking. Did you write your own FAKE build file? Or did you blindly copy it from somewhere?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand: you have some tests and you want them run whenever the larger project is built but you don't know where/how to insert the tests into you larger proejct.  Is that right?

Comment: What you have is not an xUnit test. It's just a function; nothing currently makes it a test. Also, in .NET, a project generally corresponds to a resulting DLL. You cannot compile a single code file, but only a complete project, that means all the .fs files your .fsproj file references. It is common practice in .NET to have separate projects for "production" code and tests, although in such a simple case that might not be necessary. You still need to have a proper test with a `[<Fact>]` or `[<Theory>]` attribute, though.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin It's the default FAKE file that comes with an Ionide console project.

Comment: @Steven That's correct. I started a new Ionide project to complete one of Mark Seeman's FsCheck tutorials.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev I should have been more precise. The tests have `FsCheck` property tests.